# Dummy Output Ubtutu 20.04

Tags: drivers, sound, asus

I've run this script after not being able to determine what's going wrong, i've seen that the snd-hda-intel module is definitely not loading.

wget -O alsa-info.sh http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh && chmod +x ./alsa-info.sh && ./alsa-info.sh

Output Below:

```
!!Linux Distribution
!!------------------

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS \n \l DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04 LTS" NAME="Ubuntu" ID=ubuntu ID_LIKE=debian PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04 LTS" HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/" SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/" BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/" PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy" UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal


!!DMI Information
!!---------------

Manufacturer:      System manufacturer
Product Name:      System Product Name
Product Version:   System Version
Firmware Version:  0601
Board Vendor:      ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
Board Name:        PRIME Z370-P


!!ACPI Device Status Information
!!---------------

/sys/bus/acpi/devices/ACPI000C:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT33A1:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT340E:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3F0D:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:00/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:01/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:02/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/MSFT0101:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0103:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0501:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:02/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:04/status      3
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:06/status      3
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C04:00/status      31
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0C:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0E:00/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:00/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:01/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:02/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:03/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:04/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:05/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:06/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:07/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:68/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:77/status   11


!!Kernel Information
!!------------------

Kernel release:    5.4.0-37-generic
Operating System:  GNU/Linux
Architecture:      x86_64
Processor:         x86_64
SMP Enabled:       Yes


!!ALSA Version
!!------------

Driver version:     k5.4.0-37-generic
Library version:    1.2.2
Utilities version:  1.2.2


!!Loaded ALSA modules
!!-------------------



!!Sound Servers on this system
!!----------------------------

Pulseaudio:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pulseaudio)
      Running - Yes


!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------

--- no soundcards ---


!!PCI Soundcards installed in the system
!!--------------------------------------

00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio [8086:a2f0]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 200 Series PCH HD Audio [1043:86c7]
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:10f0] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. GP104 High Definition Audio Controller [3842:5671]


!!Modprobe options (Sound related)
!!--------------------------------

snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_usb_caiaq: index=-2
snd_usb_ua101: index=-2
snd_usb_us122l: index=-2
snd_usb_usx2y: index=-2
snd_cmipci: mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2


!!Loaded sound module options
!!---------------------------


!!ALSA Device nodes
!!-----------------

crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 Jun 11 19:35 /dev/snd/seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 Jun 11 19:35 /dev/snd/timer


!!Aplay/Arecord output
!!--------------------

APLAY

aplay: device_list:274: no soundcards found...

ARECORD

arecord: device_list:274: no soundcards found...

!!Amixer output
!!-------------


!!Alsactl output
!!--------------

--startcollapse--
--endcollapse--


!!All Loaded Modules
!!------------------

acpi_pad
aesni_intel
ahci
asus_wmi
aufs
auth_rpcgss
autofs4
binfmt_misc
bpfilter
br_netfilter
bridge
cfg80211
coretemp
crc32_pclmul
crct10dif_pclmul
cryptd
crypto_simd
drm
drm_kms_helper
eeepc_wmi
fb_sys_fops
ff_memless
ghash_clmulni_intel
glue_helper
grace
hid
hid_generic
i2c_i801
ie31200_edac
input_leds
intel_cstate
intel_powerclamp
intel_rapl_common
intel_rapl_msr
intel_rapl_perf
ip6_tables
ip6t_REJECT
ip6t_rt
ip6table_filter
ip_tables
ipmi_devintf
ipmi_msghandler
ipt_REJECT
iptable_filter
iptable_mangle
iptable_nat
isofs
joydev
kvm
kvm_intel
libahci
libarc4
libcrc32c
llc
lockd
lp
mac80211
mac_hid
mc
mei
mei_hdcp
mei_me
mxm_wmi
nf_conntrack
nf_conntrack_netlink
nf_defrag_ipv4
nf_defrag_ipv6
nf_log_common
nf_log_ipv4
nf_log_ipv6
nf_nat
nf_reject_ipv4
nf_reject_ipv6
nfnetlink
nfs_acl
nfsd
nls_iso8859_1
nls_utf8
nvidia
nvidia_drm
nvidia_modeset
nvidia_uvm
overlay
parport
parport_pc
ppdev
r8169
realtek
rtl8192c_common
rtl8192ce
rtl_pci
rtlwifi
sch_fq_codel
snd
snd_rawmidi
snd_seq
snd_seq_device
snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer
soundcore
sparse_keymap
stp
sunrpc
syscopyarea
sysfillrect
sysimgblt
uas
usb_storage
usbhid
uvcvideo
vboxdrv
vboxnetadp
vboxnetflt
veth
video
videobuf2_common
videobuf2_memops
videobuf2_v4l2
videobuf2_vmalloc
videodev
wmi
wmi_bmof
x86_pkg_temp_thermal
x_tables
xfrm_algo
xfrm_user
xpad
xt_CHECKSUM
xt_LOG
xt_MASQUERADE
xt_addrtype
xt_comment
xt_conntrack
xt_hl
xt_limit
xt_multiport
xt_nat
xt_tcpudp


!!ALSA/HDA dmesg
!!--------------

[    0.155927] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Dell-Video)
[    0.155927] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[    0.155927] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-HPI-Hybrid-Graphics)


!!Packages installed
!!--------------------

ii  alsa-tools                                    1.1.7-1ubuntu1                        amd64        Console based ALSA utilities for specific hardware
ii  alsa-tools-gui                                1.1.7-1ubuntu1                        amd64        GUI based ALSA utilities for specific hardware
ii  alsa-topology-conf                            1.2.2-1                               all          ALSA topology configuration files
ii  alsa-ucm-conf                                 1.2.2-1                               all          ALSA Use Case Manager configuration files
ii  alsa-utils                                    1.2.2-1ubuntu1                        amd64        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
```

Comment: Can confirm works on a live distro, if that helps.